# PHP object lifetime

Tags: php, function, object, scope

Once my files started going 100+ lines, I started thinking about splitting them into functional parts. Then I encountered a problem, which is presented in simplified code below. I know that HTTP is stateless and objects and variables don't survive into another script unless stored into session or DB. What I'm confused is why won't it work this way?

```
 <?php

 class Student{

     public $name;
     public $age;
 }

 function do_first(){

     $student1 = new Student();
     $student1->name = "Michael";
     $student1->age = 21;
     echo $student1->name . "</br>";
 }

 function do_second(){
    echo $student1->age;  
 }

 do_first();
 do_second();

 ?>
```

I get an error in *echo $student1->age;* line saying:

```
    Undefined variable: student1 ... Trying to get property of non-object ...
```

Comment: Variable is defined in another scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables defined in a function are within that functions' **scope**.

You will need to either define the student in the global scope and pass it in as a parameter:

```
$student1 = new Student();

function do_first(Student $student) {
    $student->name = 'Michael';
}

do_first($student1);
```

**OR:**

Use the global keyword (which is horrible in my opinion)

```
function do_first() {
    global $student1; // Pull $student1 from the global scope
    $student1 = new Student();
    // ...
}

function do_second {
    global $student1; // Pull $student1 from the global scope
}
```